# Link Microsoft Excel to Word document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

I need to link certain numbers in my word document to an excel file that I have.

For example, the Revenue for FY2014 is "20,000". I would like the 20,000 to be linked to a certain cell in an excel file.

Is there any embedding or code I can write to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Linking Excel Data Into Word Documents](http://www.k2e.com/tech-update/tips/158-linking-excel-data-into-word-documents)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks alot!

I have a related question. What if I change the filename of the source excel file? Is there a quick and dirty way to update the links?

Comment: Your goal is to have word populate excel or excel populate word?

Comment: insert excel cell into word.